# Are there differences between .img and .tif formats which affects how GDAL .SetNoDataValue() works?

Tags: gis, raster, gdal, file-type

I'm having an issue masking No Data values from a statistical analysis of raster image data.

The input file is a 3-dimensional (rows, columns and layers) .img file
It is opened using the gdal.Open() function and then I want to extract some per layer statistics from each row x column image it contains (layer).

Some of these images contain crap data (or No Data), which has been given a value of -0.0 by the dataset originators. I do not want these pixel values to be included in the statistics calculations, and need to screen them out.
For this i'm using the SetNoDataValue() function, which works well on .tif imagery.

Unfortunately, with .img, -0.0 keeps showing up as each layer's minimum value (it should be around 270.something) in the minCubeValues variable, and the mean and standard deviation values are incorrect as a consequence.

When i've run this sequence on .tif files, it works fine, but it does not for .img files, and I can't figure out why.
I need to get it working directly on .img files as the bulk of my image data are in .img, and are made available as such.

I suspect it comes down to structural differences between .img and .tif files, but I cannot understand how this is being drawn into the ds2 variable.

Anyone experienced this issue before and figured out what was happening?

Code is as follows:

```
inputFilePathName = str("C:\\ResearchProcess\\2011sst_sstklcube20170628.img")
noDataValue = (-0.0)

ds2 = gdal.Open(inputFilePathName)

layerList = []
minCubeValues = []
maxCubeValues = []
layerMeans = []

for layer in range( ds2.RasterCount ):
    layer += 1
    srcLayer = ds2.GetRasterBand(layer)
    srcLayer.SetNoDataValue(noDataValue) # screens out the No Data value in .tif, for .img, it doesn't :/
    stats = srcLayer.ComputeStatistics( 0 )

    layerList.append(layer)
    minCubeValues.append(stats[0])
    maxCubeValues.append(stats[1])
    layerMeans.append(stats[2])

print minCubeValues

ds2 = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion by [Gabriella Giordano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50346345/9734224) to adapt the approach [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54150/gdal-does-not-ignore-nodata-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) works beautifully. Had to create a third variable ds3Array as i had to run through the layered data arrays layer by layer in the wider algorithm.

Cheers :)

Working code as follows.

```
ds2 = gdal.Open(inputFilePathName)
ds2Array = ds2.ReadAsArray()

layerList = []
minCubeValues = []
maxCubeValues = []
layerMeans = []
layerStdevs = []

for layer in range( ds2.RasterCount ):
    layer += 1
    ds3Array = ds2Array[layer -1]
    ds3Array = np.ma.masked_equal(ds3Array, noDataValue)

    minCubeValues.append(ds3Array.min())
    layerMeans.append(ds3Array.mean())
    layerStdevs.append(ds3Array.std())
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ERDAS imagine (.img) does not support nodata values as GeoTiff or other formats that define a mask to get rid of them.
As stated in the documentation of the SetNodataValue() API that you can find [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723222834/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALRasterBand.html#a6c7625813411cb5f0500e72d963249c2), the effect of setting a nodata value is therefore driver-dependent.

Nevertheless, for this specific case you could try [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54150/gdal-does-not-ignore-nodata-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (go to second answer provided by user Mike T).

Comment: Will do, and let you know whether it works or not. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you! Corrected code posted as an answer. Cheers for your help.